# Call as two or more times a method by clicking a single element in textillate.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Does not work

```
$(".one").click(function() {
    $('#myspan').textillate({ in: { effect: 'flash' } });
});

$(".two").click(function() {
    $('#myspan').text("new_text");
    $('#myspan').textillate({ in: { effect: 'swing' } });
});
```

**The second call is not happening**, why?
And still cause textillate - one and the same element of the second, third ...

Answer (score 1):

You can call textillate's start method to trigger the animation.

```
var $tlt = $('.tlt').textillate({ 
    autoStart: false,
    in: { effect: 'tada' }
});

$('.start').on('click', function () {
    $tlt.textillate('start'); 
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jschr/na8jp/